# Why did my Facades stop working after updating to Laravel 7.3?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

I'm trying to update my website from using Laravel 5.4 to Laravel 7.3. For the most part it works, but it looks like my custom Facades are not working for some reason...

Anytime one is used I get the following error...

[image: https://puu.sh/Frx1M/983bd578c7.png]

Here are the related files...

**App\Helpers\MyLogHelper.php**

```
namespace App\Helpers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

class MyLogHelper
{
  public function __construct()
  {

  }

  public function Log($file_name, $message)
  {
    $file_name = $file_name . '.log';
    $message = date('d-m-Y G:i:s - ') . $message;
    if(!Storage::disk('log')->exists($file_name))
    {
      Storage::disk('log')->put($file_name, $message);
    }
    else
    {
      Storage::disk('log')->append($file_name, $message);
    }
  }   
}
```

**App\Providers\MyLogServiceProvider.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use App\Helpers\MyLogHelper;

class MyLogServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{

  /**
   * Register the application services.
   *
   * @return void
   */
  public function register()
  {
     $this->app->bind('mylog', function($app){
        return new MyLogHelper();
     });
  }
}
```

**App\Facades\MyLog.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Facades;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade;

class MyLog extends Facade
{
  /**
   * Get the registered name of the component.
   *
   * @return string
   */
    protected static function getFacadeAccessor() { return 'mylog'; }
}
```

**In app.php...**

- Providers: Add the following entry "App\Providers\MyLogServiceProvider::class,"
- Aliases: Add the following entry "'MyLog' => App\Facades\MyLog::class,"

I run the following commands:

- php artisan route:cache
- composer dump-autoload

Answer (score 0):

There may be a caching issue with your config, try running `php artisan config:clear`.